# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to round a float number, to get 2 digits after point. But I am receiving the error:

> float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return round(float(self.rating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']), 2)

class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Rounding in rating field of Rating model is a bad idea, because average_rating will not round

Comment: what is `rating_set`?

Comment: @CalebGoodman get all ratings which has story field which is equal to a Story

Comment: Can you show where in your code it is defined please?

Comment: That is most likely where the problem is

Comment: @CalebGoodman  if i put just return self.rating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg'], it returns in json like "rating": 5.111111111. it defined in StorySerializer like rating = serializers.FloatField(source='average_rating', read_only=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `float` on an object like this:

```
float({'rating__avg': 2.0})
```

And not on the decimal value.

Try changing your code to this:

```
def average_rating(self):
    ratings = self.rating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
    if ratings is Not None:
        return round(float(ratings), 2)

    return None
```

this:

```
 model.objects.all().aggregate(...)
```

will return {'ratings__avg', None}

if the resulting query from `model.objects.all()` is empty.

I'm really not sure why this is happening in your code.

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov Alright I added another update.   See if that fixes it.

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov I updated with a short explanation to why you need that.

Comment: yes, looks very strange, just need to remember, thanks